# .git/info/exclude replacement for git submodule?

Tags: git, gitignore

I'm having python script to download dependencies for my library (that is extracted as git **repository**) and it adds lines to `.git/info/exclude` for git repository. But when it's extracted as **submodule** no .git/info/exclude file exists and i still need to exclude some paths without adding them to '.gitignore'. Any change to do it?

```
repo
├─.git
│ └─info
│   └─exclude
└─mylibrary (as_submodule)
  ├─extract_deps.py
  └─some_dep  (created by `extract_deps.py` and should be excluded)
```

In the picture above i need to exclude `some_dep` from git changes.

Adding `mylibrary/some_dep` to `repo/.git/info/exclude` does not help since `git status` still shows that `mylibrary/some_dep` is added and untracked.

Comment: Can be solved by adding `ignore = dirty` to `.gitsubmodules` for submodule. Any better solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Seems that git adds another structure for modules in `mainrepo/.git/modules/path-to-submodule/info/exclude`.

Adding path to your model:

```
    repo
    ├─.git
    │ ├─info
    │ ├─└─exclude
    │ └─modules
    │   └─mylibrary
    │     └─info
    │       └─exclude (for mylibrary module)
    └─mylibrary (as_submodule)
      ├─extract_deps.py
      └─some_dep  (created by extract_deps.py and should be excluded)
```

Hope this solved your issue! It definitely helped me out.

Comment: just a brief note that `.git` in submodule directory is file with actual repo location, not a directory like for git repository